# selecting item from context-menu after right click

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a website that i want to crawl but as it is in chinese i have to firsttraslate it to english and then crawl for which i want the script to right click and open the context menu and then select translate to english. my script is able to right click and open the context menu but not able to select the translate to english option

i have used selenium webdriver for chrome along with python3.7 and have written the code accordingly for right clicking and opening the context menu but stuck on selecting the option translate to english

```
path_to_chromedriver = 'C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37-32/chromedriver_new.exe'
driver =webdriver.Chrome(path_to_chromedriver)
driver.get("https://tmall.com")

your_link = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="header"]/div/div/div/div[1]')
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

actionChains.context_click(your_link).perform()
```

i expect the output to click the option translate to english from context menu

Answer (score 0):

Try simulating pressing the UP key several times (in my context menu it is 4th from the bottom in order to reach "Translate to English"):

```
actionChains.context_click(your_link).key_down(Keys.UP).key_up(Keys.UP).key_down(Keys.UP).key_up(Keys.UP).key_down(Keys.UP).key_up(Keys.UP).key_down(Keys.UP).key_up(Keys.UP).key_down(Keys.RETURN).key_up(Keys.RETURN).perform()
```

Comment: hi still not able to use the above thing can you simulate it for the website specifically i mentioned as it is not working on it

Comment: I forgot to add RETURN key press up and down. Can you try now?

Comment: nothing man just clicks the context menu but still not clicks on translate to english